# Access php function from different pages

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP function earlier today, and the function is being used by several pages on my website. It would be pretty good if I only had to have the function in one place, so that i don´t have to edit the function on every page if I want to make an adjustment.

I tried putting the function on an own page, and then I used include() to access it, but it didn't work. Is there any way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Why did it not work to put it into a separate php file and include that file?

Comment: This question calls for a: *Show us teh codez.*

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named functions.inc.php and put it in the same folder with your main php file

Put your function inside

```
<?php
function yourfunctionname (){
...
}
?>
```

Then in your main php file do

```
<?php
include("functions.inc.php");
?>
```

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Check the path you provided in your include/require-statement.

If you just provided the filename, then you have to add its directory to include_path in the  propper php.ini for example.

[include()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)